# Get original array indices after #combination

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am learning Ruby and one issue I have come across in a few practice problems is working with combinations from an array, but getting the original array indices instead of the actual combination as a result. To keep it simple let's just talk about pairs. I know a fast way to get all possible pairs is:

```
array = [a, b, c]
array.combination(2).to_a   
# => [[a, b], [a, c], [b, c]]
```

Now let's say I want to iterate over these combinations and choose a pair that fits an arbitrary condition. It would be easy enough to return the pair itself:

```
...select{|pair| condition}
# => [a, c] 
# assuming this pair fits the condition
```

but what if I want to return the indices from the original array instead?

```
# => [0, 2]
```

Is there a way of doing this using `#combination` ? Or would you have to find the combinations yourself in this case? If so is there a more elegant way to do it than the following(which is what I ended up doing to solve these problems)?

```
array.each.with_index do |s1, i1|
 array[(i1 + 1)..-1].each.with_index do |s2, i2|
  if condition
    result = [i1, (i2 + i1 + 1)]
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Is this question equivalent to, "how do I obtain the index of an element of an array"? That is, does it have anything to do with `combination`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
array.combination(s).to_a.reduce do |memo, pair|
  if condition  # I tested with pair[0] == 'a' && pair[1] == 'c'
    memo = pair.map {|e| array.index(e)}
  else
    memo
  end
end
```

My test of this yielded:

```
[0, 2]
```

**edit**

To avoid using a call to index, just compute the indexes ahead of time and then create a combination of them, selecting the one(s) that meet the condition:

```
(0..array.length).to_a.combination(2).to_a.select {|pair| condition}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using Array#index in the case that elements repeat and order matters. For example, say you wanted to find the pair with the highest difference  from an array
array = [1, 2, 3, 100, 3]. array.index(3) would return 2, when you are actually looking for the "3" at index 4.

Comment: @Damon Ahh, okay, makes sense. It just hit me that there might be an even easier solution -- I'll try it and update my answer if it works.

Comment: Your edit was very helpful, I'm going to play around with that. I would upvote but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation :)

Comment: Damon, what do you mean by, "...when you are actually looking for the "3" at index 4"? That sounds like an additional criterion that is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Cary, I just wanted to point out that I am looking for a generalized solution, rather than one that works only if all elements in the array are unique. #index doesn't work if elements repeat because it only returns the first instance of that element.

Comment: Damon, in that case, you should have mentioned that in the question, though I don't know what "generalized solution" means. Also, "...it only returns the first instance of that element" is not necessarily true. You could return the indices of all elements in the array that have a given value, but again, that has nothing to do with `combination`.

Comment: A generalized solution is one that applies to many or all cases, or, is an exact match for the question at hand rather than something that gives the result only if a specific case is true. #index is situational because it looks up the index of an element, but does not consider cases in which (given multiple same elements) the order or exact position of the element you are referencing matters. 
The solution neuronaut provided after "edit" works both in cases where #index would work, and in cases where it would not, therefore I consider it a generalized solution.